# Pandas Python How to get sum of all other rows except the row that contains the sum

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I want to create a column like the 'sum' below from 'col1', where all elements of column 'sum' are the sum of the other rows of col1

```py
col1    sum
1       9 (3+5+1)
3       7
5       5
1       9
```

Comment: How do you know which row contains the sum?

Comment: @DanielR I start with col1 and I try to build column 'sum' by adding all elements of the other rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be pretty straight forward:

```
df['sum'] = df['x'].sum()-df['x']
print(df)

   x  sum
0  1    9
1  3    7
2  5    5
3  1    9
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a column which substract the row of col1 to the total of the column row1.

This might work :

```
sum_col1 = df['col1'].sum()

def minus_total(column): 
    sum_col1  - return column 

df["sum"] = df['col1'].apply(minus_total)
```

Just saw the other answer and it look better !